# "in" operator not working as expected with date strings in IE11

Tags: javascript, date

So I came across this odd interaction between Javascript Date objects being converted into Strings and the `in` operator in IE11. The String that `.toLocaleString()` returns for a date, doesn't work when checking for keys using the `in` operator, even through another string with the exact same text works just fine.

The interaction works correctly in Chrome, but seems to fail in IE11. What am I missing here and is there a way to get around this?

```js
let days = {
  Monday: {},
  Tuesday: {},
  Wednesday: {},
  Thursday: {},
  Friday: {},
  Saturday: {},
  Sunday: {}
};

// The example date should be a Monday
let currentDate = new Date('2018/8/20');
let currentDay = currentDate.toLocaleString('en-us', {
  weekday: 'long'
});

console.log(currentDay);
console.log(typeof currentDay);
console.log(currentDay in days);
console.log('Monday' in days);
```

Thanks for any input!

Comment: You've apparently missed "Invalid date" log in IE ..?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: `console.log(currentDay);` logs "Invalid date" in IE11.

Comment: Odd, sorry about that. I was getting a valid date on my localhost. I’ll double check when I get back to my computer.

Comment: `'2018-8-20T00:00'` would create a valid date in IE, or `'2018/8/20'`.

Comment: @teemu—but then you'll get an invalid Date in Safari. ;-)

Comment: Your issue is using the built-in parser, see [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results) Also, the value returned by *toLocaleString* is implementation dependent, you can't guarantee the result.

Comment: So it sounds like the solution in this case would be to use `.toString()` or `.toUTCString()` and use my own custom parser to pull out the day of the week, or use a 3rd party library like moment.js that has this built in.

Comment: @ChaseIngebritson—yes, a *real* parser and formatter would help. Moment.js is good, but there are many to choose from. Others are [*luxon*](https://moment.github.io/luxon/) (full–featured) and [*fecha*](https://github.com/taylorhakes/fecha) (small, efficient parsing and formatting). *toLocaleString* can be handy, but for comparisons it's a bit useless (implementation dependance and all that).

Comment: @RobG Thanks again for all the help! For anyone that sees this question, I ended up going with fecha and it worked perfectly for the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically why you should stick to ISO date strings (`2018-01-01T00:00Z`) and not use arbitrary formats.

Alternatively, parse the format yourself and use the other overload of the `new Date()` constructor like so:

```
const currentDate = new Date(2018, 7 /* months start at 0 */, 20 /* days do not */, 0, 0, 0)
```

Date parsing is bad, and IE is bad, and two bads don't make a good in this case.

It's not the `in` that's wrong. Your date is invalid in IE.

Comment: I guess I'm misunderstanding how if I output `Monday` from a Date object as a String and I just initialize my own String with the text `Monday` how they aren't equivalent.

Comment: How is IE worse than Safari?